npx expo install --fix installs older version of SDK instead of latest
I have a very basic react native expo project which i want to run it on SDK 51.I get this error message on Iphone Expo gp app saying "the installed version of Expo GO is for SDK 51 , the project you opened uses SDK 34".
After seeing this error message I have updated the dependencies of expo in Package.json to 51 and ran the below commands by referring the link.
https://docs.expo.dev/workflow/upgrading-expo-sdk-walkthrough/
1. npm install expo@51
2. npm install
3. npx expo install --fix
When  i run the last command I see its trying to install SDK 34 again which doesnot make any sense... I am not sure what I am doing wrong. Can someone please throw some light on this.
Output :
PS D:\React\Flex> npx expo install --fix
The following packages should be updated for best compatibility with the installed expo version:
  babel-preset-expo@11.0.10 - expected version: ^6.0.0
Your project may not work correctly until you install the correct versions of the packages.
› Installing 1 SDK 34.0.0 compatible native module using npm

package.json file
{
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "eject": "expo eject"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "expo": "^51.0.14",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.74.2",
    "react-native-web": "~0.19.6"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-preset-expo": "~11.0.0"
  },
  "private": true
}

